# Ruby on Rails using Rspec feature test, get id of object you create while the tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd, specifications

I am pretty new to Ruby On Rails and am wondering what is the best practice to get an object id (in my case it is a product id) that was created during the test.

I created a product in the feature test by filling in data in fields (not programmatically) and the product has been created successfully. **How can I get the product id for other tests?**

For example right now I need **@product_id** to provide to the following test:

```
expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path)
```

I am getting the next Error because I can't provide @product_id:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path)
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My Test:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Creating Products' do

  before do
    @user_test = User.create(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password')
    @product_test_name = 'Test product'
    @product_test_price = '20'
  end

  scenario 'User creates a new product' do
    login_as(@seller_test)
    visit '/'
    have_link 'New Product'
    visit new_product_path

    fill_in 'Name', with: @product_test_name
    fill_in 'Price', with: @product_test_price

    click_button 'Create Product'

    expect(page).to have_content('Product has been created')

    expect(page).to have_content(@product_test_name)
    expect(page).to have_content(@product_test_description)
    expect(page).to have_content(@product_test_price)

    expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path)
  end
  end
```

Please advice how to do it right.

Comment: Don't do `expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path)`  - instead do  `expect(page).to have_current_path(product_path)`  -- it doesn't solve your problem ( the answer by @dchacke does that ) but it will save you headaches in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that test inserts a product record into your database, perhaps you can do

```
product = Product.last
```

and only afterwards make the assertion

```
expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path(product)) # or product.id
```

Or use `have_current_path` in lieu of `eq` as Tom Walpole suggests in the comments.

Comment: Thank you @dchacke for your reply, it was very helpful.  <br/> product = Product.last <br/> worked well for me. In the second line of the code I made a small change: <br/> expect(page.current_path).to eq(product_path(product)) <br/> Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Oh yeah good call on the product_path, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @dchacke Prefer the `have_current_path` matcher over `eq`  - it has capybaras waiting behavior so it will wait for the current path to change if necessary - makes tests less brittle